# Method does not exist during async connectedCallback call

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, asynchronous

I have a datatable with several rows, each row representing a unique record.

I want to build a url containing the id of the record for each row, but I want to surface a label in UI, not that url.

```
   {  
        type: 'url',
        fieldName: 'driverurl',
        typeAttributes: { 
            label: 'Driver',
            target: '_blank'
        },
        hideDefaultActions: true
    }


getDriverUrl = (id) => {
    var url = '//' + window.location.hostname + '/apex/testpage';
    if (this.accountid) {
        url = url + '#!/' + encodeURIComponent(this.accountid) + '/'+id+'//test/';
    }
    return url;
}


async connectedCallback() {
    const data = await getData();
    this.mappeddata = data.map(function(i){
        return {
            id : i.Id,
            name : i.Name,
            driverurl: getDriverUrl(i.Id),
        }
    });
}
```

I get an error when I us this approach. `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: getDriverUrl is not defined at h.connectedCallback`

Can anyone tell me what the problem is here? The method does not exist during the async connectedCallback?  I've moved the method inside the connectedCallback, but I get a similar error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use arrow function for `map` method to be able to access the methods inside your JS.

```
    this.mappeddata = data.map((i) => {
        return {
            id : i.Id,
            name : i.Name,
            driverurl: this.getDriverUrl(i.Id),
        }
    });
```

Comment: That did the trick, thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad it helped.

Comment: @NagendraSingh can you explain why it's necessary to use an arrow function?  Looking at the original code from @Daft it occurs to me that they were using `getDriverUrl(i.Id)` instead of `this.getDriverUrl(i.Id)`, and I believe the omission of `this` would have also caused this error.

Comment: This is a lexical scope concept in ES6, check this out https://medium.com/better-programming/a-brief-introduction-to-closures-and-lexical-scoping-in-javascript-8a5866496232

Comment: You can read more on closure and scope in JS to understand this better.